# Clear a selection in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, mobile, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to clear a selection in Xamarin Forms because the ListView keeps populating all my selections.

How do I make it so that after i've selected an item, it will pass the selection to the next page and reset the selection? Right now it's going to the next page and then a second later it refreshes and clears the page.

Here's the ProductPage.xaml.cs when they select a product.

```
    async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        var item = (Product)e.SelectedItem;

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ProductDetailPage(item));

        ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;

    }
```

Here's the ProductDetailPage.xaml.cs

```
public ProductDetailPage(Product products)
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = products;
            
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ProductDetailPage>(this, "AddToCartProduct", (sender) =>
            {
                ShoppingCart.data.Add(products.title);

                DisplayAlert("Added to Cart!", products.title, "OK");

            });

        }
```

Here's my ViewShoppingCart.xaml.cs

```
public ViewShoppingCart()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            

            MyListView.ItemsSource = ShoppingCart.data;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the `BindingMode` for `SelectedItem` to `TwoWay`?

```
<ListView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding CustomList}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding CustomSelectedItemProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work. I'm going to try using Arrays instead.